# Live Delete Row In a Table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm currently creating an online reservation system, i have seen a a lot of codes but none of them is working on me. i only want to create a delete function which deletes the current selected item on the table. Here's a screenshot and a code:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F19T.png)

```html
?>
echo'<tr class="">
<td class="xedit" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="name">'.$fetch['name'].'</td>
<td class="xedit" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="lname">'.$fetch['lname'].'</td>
<td class="xedit" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="ticketid">'.$fetch['ticketid'].'</td>
<td class="xedit" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="vehicle">'.$fetch['vehicle'].'</td>
<td>'.$fetch['pickuptime'].'</td>
<td><div align="right"><a href="\myfelicia\uploads/'.$fetch['billing_image'].'">'.$fetch['billing_image'].'</a></div></td>
<td class="xedit" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="status">'.$fetch['status'].'</td>
<td class="delete" id="'.$fetch['id'].'" key="delete"><a href="#">Delete</a></td>
</tr>';
}
```

Comment: 1-the code you posted is all wrong, 2- what you need here is an ajax function to pass the desired ID to be deleted from the database.

Comment: first - learn what `?>` and `{}` mean

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily need AJAX for this. Do a POST request a HTML form by clicking on the delete button. Also, do not echo heaps of HTML.

```
<tr>
    <td class="xedit"><?php echo $fetch['name']; ?></td>
    <td class="delete">
        <form method="POST" action="delete.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $fetch['id'];?>">
            <button>delete</button>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now you should have a file delete.php that actually deletes the reservation by using $_POST['id']